# React navigation não redireciona na primeira vez

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, react-navigation

Boa noite, tenho um preload que redireciona o usuário para determinadas telas de acordo com alguns parâmetros, ele somente redireciona quando eu atualizo a tela do emulador.

```
import { StackActions, CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        name: state.userReducer.name
    }
}  

const Preload = (props) => {
    function onRedirect() {
        if (!props.name) {
            //mandar para starter stack
            props.navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                name: "teste",
                routes: [
                    { name: 'StarterStack' }
                ],
                actions: [
                    CommonActions.navigate({
                        name: 'StarterStack'
                    })
                ]
            }))
        } else {
            //app tab
            props.navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.reset({
                name: "AppTab",
                routes: [
                    { name: 'AppTab' }
                ],
                actions: [
                    CommonActions.navigate({
                        name: 'AppTab'
                    })
                ]
            }))
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        onRedirect();
    }, []);

    return null;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Preload);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sempre coloque as referências utilizadas como dependência do useEffect, com isso você garante que ele possui a versão mais atualizada da referência que ele está usando.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    onRedirect();
}, [onRedirect]);
```

Outra possibilidade é colocar toda a função dentro do useEffect.

Comment: Ainda não funcionou amigo, já tentei colocar console log dentro do if para ver se estava entrando mesmo e ele entra porem não redireciona.